# Add prototype function without using .prototype= in each line

Tags: javascript, extend, phaser-framework

I would like to know if there's any way that I can add prototype function without using `.prototype=` in each line

This is the current code:

```
Fruit= function( x, y, settings) {
    Phaser.Sprite.call(this,game,x,y, 'fruit');
    game.add.existing(this);
};

Fruit.prototype.basic= function() {}

Fruit.prototype = Object.create(Phaser.Sprite.prototype);
Fruit.prototype.constructor = Fruit;

//I find that writing function in the following way is very hard to focus and find what I need immediately

Fruit.prototype.move= function() {

};

Fruit.prototype.fall= function() {

};
```

I want to write my code in this way, but I need to inherit from the original Phaser prototype. Any way I can write the code in the way below while still inherit from `Phaser.Sprite.prototype`?

```
Fruit.prototype = {
    move: function () {
    },
    fall: function () {
    }
}
```

As long as I can write it in this way is fine:

```
move: function () {
},

fall: function () {
}
```

Thanks

Comment: [`defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) maybe?

Comment: Just use [ES6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: `Fruit.prototype = Object.assign({ move: ..., fall: ...}, Phaser.sprite.prototype)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understand you want to apply a set of new methods from one object to a prototype object at once.

You could do this via [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
Object.assign(Fruit.prototype, {
    move: function () {
    },

    fall: function () {
    }
});
```

This will add all properties from the 2nd to n-th parameter to the object in the 1st parameter passed to `assign()`.

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I need!